# SSRS Failing with error on App_global.asax

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

Our SSRS server has started failing. The Logs are currently showing the following error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException:
    Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\RSTempFiles\reportserver\c2a527bc\9cd1a7f9\App_global.asax.lmmhf4gb.dll' or one of its dependencies.
    This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
```

It seems like the SSRS service is compiling the web site using .NET 4.0, but it should be using v3.5 from everything we've discovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the fix here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvar/archive/2012/07/14/reporting-services-unexpectedly-loads-net-framework-4-0-by-default-and-fails-with-http-500-19-while-browsing-report-server-and-report-manager-url.aspx

Turns out that the registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\OnlyUseLatestCLR` was set to `1`. No idea how it got there. Once we changed it, everything worked again.